# Minimal set of PostgreSQL data files

Tags: postgresql, automated-tests, snapshot

**Background:** I run end-to-end tests that depend on a PostgreSQL database. I need these tests to be fast, parallelizable, deterministic, and isolated.

Therefore, I want to repeatedly recreate the database -- including schema, data, and indexes -- as quickly as possible. I create a base image:

1. start a PostgreSQL instance
2. run SQL statements
3. run `VACCUM FULL`
4. stop the instance
5. tar the files in `/var/lib/postgresql/data`

For each test I then quickly untar that image and run a PostgreSQL instance.

---

**Problem:** This all works, but the disk files seem larger than necessary. A rather small database is still 64MB in size.

How can I achieve a smaller set of files for file-level restores? Shrink the size of the existing files? Exclude some files from the backup?

Comment: Why not instantiate them from a customised template?

Comment: @wildplasser, I suppose could do that, if I reused the same PostgreSQL instance.

Comment: If that is not what you want, you could remove all databases except `template0` and `postgres`. It won't get much smaller than that.

Comment: Have you considered docker? It won't save you space, but it's simple and fast.

Comment: *why* do you want to `tar` the (binary)files? Do you need them for post-mortem investigations, or to re-initialise the next run?

Comment: If you look into the data directory, there are also thw WAL-files. You can shrink that, but it will likely cost you performance. And yes, what is your goal? Why do you pack and unpack the data directory?

Comment: @teppic, I do use docker for this. Each test starts a PostgreSQL instance (and other containers).

Comment: @wildplasser + Sherbaum, I don't necessarily need to have a single tar file...though it is convenient (since that that's how Make operates). I really just need to be able to have an way to copy the base set of data for each PostgreSQL instance that I launch during the tests.

Comment: @PaulDraper you don't need to recreate the database then, just commit and tag the container in the test state (without using external volumes).

Comment: @teppic, ah I see. Leverage the docker copy-on-write file system. That is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for making plain your use case:

> I run end-to-end tests that depend on a PostgreSQL database. I need these tests to be fast, parallelizable, deterministic, and isolated.
>
> Therefore, I want to repeatedly recreate the database -- including schema, data, and indexes -- as quickly as possible.

The initial idea – to locate a specific set of files by path, and restore those – is fragile because the paths can and do change with different PostgreSQL versions.

As discussed in comments, a more deterministic way to do this is with more general container technologies; one that is well trodden and [suitable for the use case](https://www.twistlock.com/2017/08/22/using-containers-make-software-tests-faster-secure/) is [Docker](https://www.docker.com/). There are [various other container options](https://techbeacon.com/enterprise-it/essential-guide-software-containers-application-development) also.

The documentation for Docker has an example of [how to set up a container running PostgreSQL](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/postgresql_service/).